# Adding the debug token of Firebase App Check generated using Firebase console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-check

Looking at this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/debug-provider?authuser=0&hl=en), it shows that one should add the debug token generated in logs after running an app. However this is not doable when your app is being delivered and tested in a CI CD pipeline with Firebase Test Lab. In the console you can add and/or generate debug token, in case of generating token using the console I assume that token can be set as parameter or configuration when initializing App Check.

Unfortunately I cannot see any public method where I can set the debug token generated using console. My current code is this:

```
FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance().installAppCheckProviderFactory(

  if (debug)
    DebugAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance() // Where to add the debug token generated from console?
  else
    PlayIntegrigtyAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance()
    
)
```

If I remember correctly, the above code when run will generate a debug token via logs if it is a debug build. What we need is the opposite, we generate token via console then add it to the build so it can run in CI CD with Firebase Test Lab.

Comment: See if this solution works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76991928/firebase-app-check-doesnt-work-with-debug-tokens/78027528#78027528

Answer (score 1):

[From the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/debug-provider#ci) it states that you will need to add

```
testInstrumentationRunnerArgument "firebaseAppCheckDebugSecret", System.getenv("APP_CHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN_FROM_CI") ?: ''
```

This has a system environment variable setup in the code as to not read it from the project itself. What you could do is set the system environment variable on the machine that the project runs on and then Android will automatically grab that token and supply it to the debug provider supplied.

Comment: I don't understand this part, where should I put this code? In the gradle build or in CI CD script?

Comment: In the app/build.gradle for the debug variant

Comment: Is `DebugAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance()` still needed here? Anyway after applying this we are getting error after sync. `Could not find method testInstrumentationRunnerArgument() for arguments [firebaseAppCheckDebugSecret, the-debug-token]`

Comment: What happens if you change it to testInstrumentationRunnerArguments with an 's' on the end? I'm looking at Android docs and our docs might have missed the last s - https://developer.android.com/training/testing/instrumented-tests/androidx-test-libraries/runner

Comment: I already did that actually, adding 's' since I also didn't see any documentation about testInstrumentationRunnerArgument but rather testInstrumentationRunnerArguments