# Firebase App Check doesn't work with debug tokens

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-check

I use [Firebase App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/play-integrity-provider). **It was working verry well for months** but today it stopped working in debug environment.

---

In my app I have:

```
  FirebaseAppCheck firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance();

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(DebugAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance(), true);
        } else {
            firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(PlayIntegrityAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance(), true);
        }
```

---

When I would like to run my app in a debug environment on a real device I get the following error:

```
 (24.2.1) [Firestore]: Write failed at my_db_name/my_user@mail.com: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
```

---

However, I did add a debug token to Firebase App Check right here:

[image]

---

Also, the debug token which I got from the logs **changes every time I ran the app, is that normal?**

> Enter this debug secret into the allow list in the Firebase Console
> for your project: 82ad4db7-2d51-48vb-bb53-deb9f610ad7c

Why is it still telling me I have no permission?

What is the average waiting time I have to wait before Firebase actually changes state?

Comment: The error message "Missing or insufficient permissions" means that Firebase App Check is not able to verify the authenticity of your app..To fix this error, you need to make sure that the debug token you added is correct and that it has not expired. You can also try running your app in debug mode

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: @Alex I didn't. It is a stinking pile of s.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77286668/reuse-debug-appcheck-token-in-ios-simulator

Answer (score 1):

I found a couple of reasons why this might happen:

- Patch update from Firebase
- App Check token expires due to the user being signed out

This [GitHub post](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5842) is a bit old but has the same concern as yours, then from here a [solution](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/pull/5902) was established via [patch update  (@firebase/firestore@3.4.4)](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/pull/5939#@firebase/firestore@3.4.4).

Check if you are getting some FirebaseAuth notifications about sign-out events in auth state or id token listeners when trying another data load request. These events trigger the PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions error message.

These documents might also be helpful for you:

- [Use App Check with the debug provider on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/debug-provider)
- [Verify App Check tokens from a custom backend](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/custom-resource-backend)
- [Understand Firebase Realtime Database Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/)

Answer (score 0):

> Also, the debug token which I got from the logs changes every time I
> ran the app, is that normal?

Yes, it changes every time when you reinstall the app.

However you can implement a custom **AppCheckProviderFactory** to prevent this.

**1. Add a new debug token in the Firebase (Manage debug tokens)**
[image: Add a new debug token]
**2. Implemnet the CustomAppCheckProviderFactory with the previously generated debug secret.**

```
class   CustomAppCheckProviderFactory : AppCheckProviderFactory {
    private val NUMBER_OF_CORES = 1
    private val backgroundPriorityThreadFactory = SimpleThreadFactory()

    private val executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(
        NUMBER_OF_CORES * 2,
        NUMBER_OF_CORES * 2,
        60L,
        TimeUnit.SECONDS,
        LinkedBlockingQueue(),
        backgroundPriorityThreadFactory
    )
    private val provider = CustomProvider()
    override fun create(firebaseApp: FirebaseApp): AppCheckProvider {
        return DebugAppCheckProvider(
            firebaseApp,
            provider,
            executor,
            executor,
            executor
        )
    }
}

internal class CustomProvider : Provider<InternalDebugSecretProvider> {
    private val internalDebugSecretProvider = CustomDebugSecretProvider()
    override fun get(): InternalDebugSecretProvider {
        return internalDebugSecretProvider
    }
}

internal class CustomDebugSecretProvider : InternalDebugSecretProvider {
    override fun getDebugSecret(): String {
        return BuildConfig.APP_CHECK_DEBUG_SECRET //or your generated app check secret
    }
}

internal class SimpleThreadFactory : ThreadFactory {
    override fun newThread(r: Runnable?): Thread {
        return Thread(r)
    }
}
```

**3. Install the CustomAppCheckProviderFactory when the build is a debug build.**

```
FirebaseAppCheck firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance();

if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(CustomAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance(), true);
} else {
    firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(PlayIntegrityAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance(), true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found below solution to keep the taken same always just like we do in [iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77286668/reuse-debug-appcheck-token-in-ios-simulator) by passing it though manage env.

Step 1:
I placed my key in local.properties as

```
firebase.debug.token=ABCD_ACB8-BBAC-409F-AE68-74E4A7F4_XYZ
```

Step 2:
in app module build.gradle.kts
(focus on buildTypes.debug)

```
  buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
            buildConfigField("String", "FB_DEBUG_TOKEN", "\"\"")
        }
        debug {
            isDebuggable = true
            val key: String = gradleLocalProperties(rootDir).getProperty("firebase.debug.token") ?: ""
            buildConfigField("String", "FB_DEBUG_TOKEN", "\"$key\"")
        }
    }
```

In buildFeatures you need to add buildConfig = true

```
buildFeatures {
    compose = true
    buildConfig = true
}
```

Step 3: In MainActivity.kt or in the class where you are initialising Firebase

```
  Firebase.appCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            val storageHelper = StorageHelper(FirebaseApp.getInstance().applicationContext,  FirebaseApp.getInstance().persistenceKey)
            storageHelper.saveDebugSecret(BuildConfig.FB_DEBUG_TOKEN)
            println("APP_CHECK -storageHelper ---->> debugKey: --- ${storageHelper.retrieveDebugSecret()}")
            println("APP_CHECK - ON DEBUG SIMULATOR MODE ************************")
            DebugAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance()
        } else {
            println("APP_CHECK - ON RELEASE MODE ************************")
            PlayIntegrityAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance()
        }
    )
```

Comment: There is no `saveDebugSecret`  method from `StorageHelper`